# Book about a boarding school girl connected by soul to a boy she can't kiss

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read this book between 2013 and 2015.

In the book, a girl's parents die (they may have been related to supernatural hunters or hunted). She is put in a boarding school where she is attracted to a boy.

It turns out that she is attracted because her soul was once his. They fight romance because if they kiss, he would take her soul.

In the end they kiss and he temporarily takes her soul. He loves her and gives it back and turns into an old man.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might this be *[Dead Beautiful](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7875327-dead-beautiful)* (2010) by Yvonne Woon, the first book in the [Dead Beautiful](https://www.goodreads.com/series/57369-dead-beautiful) series...?

[This review](http://www.thebookbag.co.uk/reviews/Dead_Beautiful_by_Yvonne_Woon) offers some details about the plot which seem to match your description pretty closely:

> **Renee is a normal school girl living in sunny California. On her sixteenth birthday she is drawn to the woods by her house. There she finds the dead bodies of her parents, surrounded by scattered coins, and shreds of cloth in their mouths.** The police say they both died from a heart attack, but Renee isn't convinced — something more sinister must be going on.
>
> **Sent away to Gottfried Academy by her old, and very strict, Grandfather, Renee has to leave her home and friends to study at a school she can find nothing about in any books or the internet.** When she gets there she's thrown into studying Latin, Horticulture and Ancient Civilisations. **It's also where she meets Dante – intelligent, handsome and aloof.** More confusing is that the students can't decide whether they love him or are afraid of him. The one thing Renee knows is that when she's around him her grief falls away and she feels alive.
>
> But not everything is rosy at Gottfried Academy; students are going missing and turning up dead. The cause of death – heart attacks. **As Renee gets more tangled in trying to find out what's happening to her new friends and also what really happened to her parents, her life becomes more intertwined with Dante. But does finding your soulmate mean literally that, someone who shares your soul?**